# How to override ggplot2's axis formatting?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When you choose a log scale, ggplot2 formats the breaks like 10^x.  I'd like it to not do that.  For example, the code below should display a graph with ticks at 1, 2, 5 etc, not 10^0, 10^0.3, 10^0.69 etc.

```
library(ggplot2)
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rlnorm(100))
breaks <- as.vector(c(1, 2, 5) %o% 10^(-1:1))
p1 <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10(breaks = breaks)
print(p1)
```

I guess that adding a `formatter` argument to `scale_y_log10` would do the trick, but I'm not sure what to put in the argument, or where the options might be documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scale_y_log10(breaks = breaks, labels = breaks` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

As of ggplot2 version 0.9.0, this behavior (formatting the axis labels as 10^0) is no longer the default.  The code in the question now gives the desired result.

```
library(ggplot2)
dfr <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rlnorm(100))
breaks <- as.vector(c(1, 2, 5) %o% 10^(-1:1))
p1 <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_log10(breaks = breaks)
print(p1)
```

[image]