# GGplot2: plot histogram with log scale but linear values?

Tags: r, logging, ggplot2, scale

I created a histogram with ggplot2 in R and need a logarithmically spaced x-axis, but would like to keep my linear values.

Is this possible?

My formula so far is:

```
ggplot(f0peruttnq, aes(f0)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.3, fill='white', colour='black')
```

Slightly off-topic: I also tried to superimpose a normal curve on top of my histogram, but geom_density() doesn't seem to work if I want to keep my counts instead of density values on the x-axis. As I tried + stat_function( fun = dnorm ) nothing changed at all!

Thanks in advance for any useful tips!

It's working now!

Formula I used:

```
ggplot(data, aes(V2)) + geom_histogram(alpha=0.3, fill='white', colour='black')+scale_x_log10(breaks=c(50,100,150,200,250),labels=c(50,100,150,200,250))
```

Thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: Please post a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  You'll get better help, and we'll be less grumpy :-)

Comment: Hm...basically I want a graph that looks like it was created from log values, just that there are linear values on the x-axis! This is my histogram: http://www7.pic-upload.de/06.08.11/rzr5ftih1a.jpg. It was created from log values and these values are on the x-axis. I want the same histogram, but created from linear values! The shape of the histogram should look like in the picture, but the labelling of the x-axis should be given in linear values! My formula so far is:  ggplot(f0peruttnq, aes(f0))+geom_histogram(alpha=0.3, fill='white', colour='black')

Comment: Please edit your question to add in the formula that you have so far (push the {} code button with your code highlighted to mark your code as code) and the output of `dput(f0peruttnq)` and `dput(f0)`.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean to not transform your data but only the plot?  If so, it's easy:

Modified example from the ggplot2 [help pages](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_continuous.html):

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- subset(movies, votes > 1000)
m <- qplot(rating, votes, data=dat, na.rm = T)
bks <- seq(min(dat$rating),max(dat$rating))
m + scale_x_log10(breaks=bks,labels=bks)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for then.  Do you want the scale to be wrong, since it would have linear labels and log values?  Or do you want the X axis to be log transformed?

Comment: I want the x-axis to be log transformed with linear labels. If that doesn't work, then I want the scale to be wrong.

Comment: Like it is now?  What do you mean by linear labels?  10,000 instead of 10^4 ?

Comment: The y-axis looks fine now, but I'd like to keep my values in Hz, which range from 60-400. So, yes!

Comment: Like now?  See this question for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699493/transform-only-one-axis-to-log10-scale-with-ggplot2

Comment: This is exactly what I want! The problem is, when I try `ggplot(f0peruttnq, aes(f0)) + 
geom_histogram(alpha=0.3, fill='white', colour='black')+  scale_x_log10( breaks=breaks,labels = breaks)`, I get the error `Error in match.fun(get(".transform", .))(values) : non-numerical argument for mathematical function` What do I have to do to transform my 10^x values to normal integers?

Comment: Help us help you.  Please edit your original question (click the "Edit" button under it) and provide the information I asked for above.

Comment: I added it, sorry for the chaotic formatting, I didn't know how to change that! Also, I didn't get the beginning of the output, probably because I have thousands of values.

Comment: We'd need the whole thing.  The purpose of dput() is that it lets us re-create your objects in our R, to play with them.  We'd only need the first few rows though.  Try `head(dput(f0peruttnq))` and `head(dput(f0))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible with ggplot2 but if you're not absolutely tied to that library, I'm 99% sure you can do it with the `axis()` function of the standard `graphics` library.

With all due respect, and with no intention of creating a discussion here (we can take it to chat if you want), but isn't doing this misleading? The labels on the x-axis should reflect their actual values. Since you are log-transforming the data, the axis labels should reflect that transformation. To do otherwise would be scientifically dishonest.

---

Edited for an example of using the `graphics` library...not as pretty as ggplot2 but it does what you want (note: I was wrong about having to edit the histogram's breaks):

```
> data <- log(rnorm(10000, 100, 10))  #simulate some data that looks like yours
> hist(data) # view a normal histogram of the data with log values on the x-axis
> tick_locations = c(4.2, 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 5.0)  # copy the tick locations from the normal plot
> tick_labels = exp(tick_locations) # reverse the log transformation; you can also create this manually
> hist(data, xaxt = "n")  # plot without the x-axis
> axis(1, at = tick_locations, labels = tick_labels) # add the x-axis with the de-transformed values
```

Comment: To clarify about using the `graphics` package:
In your initial call to plot, use the argument xaxt="n" to suppress plotting the x-axis. Then call `axis(side=1, at=vector_of_tick_positions, labels=vector_of_tick_labels)` along with whatever other arguments you need.

Comment: Ah, sorry I referred to `plot()` but it should also work with `hist()`. You'll also have to specify where the bins are located though through the `hist()` function's argument `breaks`.

Comment: Doinng `tick_labels = exp(tick_locations)` results in long floating-point values. Probably better to do it manually like `tick_labels = c(66.7, 81.5, 99.5, 121.5, 148.4)`

Comment: Thanks! Works, but in contrast to the ggplot example from gsk3, there's no logarithmical spacing on the x-axis!