# Changing Scale on Axis Using log10 in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose you have data points ranging from 10^9-10^13, that if you used ggplot, the scale on the graph would only show the order of 10^13 while anything less than that would be miniscule.

```
 ggplot(data=Category_type,
             aes(x=reorder(TYPE, dollars), y=dollars, fill=dollars )) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("type") +
  ylab("dollars") +
  ggtitle("Highest Costs") +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

What would I have to change in this statement to accommodate for points that display the bars  of  order 10^9 ?

I stumbled upon this thread but it's not exactly what I'm looking for:

[Transform only one axis to log10 scale with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699493/transform-only-one-axis-to-log10-scale-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+ coord_trans(y = 'log10')` will make a log transformed coordinate system.

Comment: That works thanks!

Comment: If I wanted to change the colour, where would that go in the above statement?

Comment: 'the colour' can refer to almost any part of a plot. You'll have to specify.

Comment: Suppose I want red bars for each category_type, they don't have to be distinct.

Comment: Also, how does one add captions for these plots?

Comment: That's all super basic stuff, just search yourself or look up a tutorial.

Comment: Give me a reference. I have searched figure caption ggplot in R but nothing comes up for grid.arrange. I don't need to do it for the whole grid, even just for the ggplot. What is the syntax? With some references they're overcomplicated. I just want a simple caption below the plot.

Comment: My search for 'figure caption ggplot in R' gives [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) page as the third hit, which shows how to do both grids _and_ captions (although it does rely on having another package). For the fanciest captions, see [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/labs.html), but you'll need the `dev` version of ggplot, which you can install from github using `devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')`. I trust you fixed your red bars then?

Comment: No where do I see a caption below the figure in the first link you provided. The second link does have one, ...+  labs(caption = "(based on data from ...)"), although it works, nothing shows when I use it. I could only find one statement that allows me to show highest bars as red and lowest as green but not all red.

Comment: The first link shows how to write text _anywhere_ on the plot. For the second, you'll need to install the dev version as I said.